# How can I insert only certain columns from a mysql table to netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, datatables

I'm doing a calendar program in Netbeans using Mysql database. there is a table for every event which has many column, one of them being a Boolean called "Tarea" (Task). This determines if the day will go on the table of Pending which should only display the date and title of the event.

To do this I used the following code:

```
 void TablaPendientes(){
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calendario";
String user = "root";
String pass = "password";
try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass))
{
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablaRecursos.getModel();
        pst=connection.prepareStatement("select Fecha, TituloE from eventos where Tarea = 1");
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        { 
            model.addRow(new String[]{rs.getString("Fecha"),  rs.getString("TituloE")});
        }
}catch(SQLException e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

I called the function form my main but it still doesn't plot the table. Can I only put all of the values of the table? I ask this because in another table that has practically the same code except that in the statement it is "select * from", it plots correctly.

Comment: No, you don't need to select all the columns. Either log some output, or step through your code with the debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Checked the debugger and at the end I just wrote the table name wrong sjshjhs.